# Haskell - How to increase integer argument in a function?

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie here! I'm trying to run some tests for a function I created that takes and outputs another number. (This is a simple function example).

```
nextNum :: Int -> Int
nextNum n = n+1
```

However, in my `main`, I don't want to constantly type out my function with

```
print $ nextNum 0
print $ nextNum 1
print $ nextNum 2
```

Is there a way to put this all in a shorter concise line where the output will be printed as a new line? I've tried lambas but I honestly don't think I'm doing it right.

```
print $ nextNum (\x -> [0..4])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fun intro to functional thinking about imperative actions.  One way to think about this is that you want to make a *list of actions*:

```
let actions = [ print (nextNum 0), print (nextNum 1), ... ]
```

This doesn't *do* anything though, it just gives a list the name `actions`.  We use the function `sequence_` (mind the underscore) to actually perform the actions:

```
sequence_ actions
```

You can make your list of actions with a list comprehension:

```
main = do
    let actions = [ print (nextNum n) | n <- [0..4] ]
    sequence_ actions
```

And of course you can "inline" the `actions` variable:

```
main = sequence_ [ print (nextNum n) | n <- [0..4] ]
```

The underscore after `sequence_` is to differentiate it from `sequence`, which collects the return value of each action and returns them all in a list.  `sequence_` just ignores the return value.

Answer (score 4):

This actually gets even shorter yet, as `mapM_` and `map` can fuse, like this:

```
mapM_ (print . nextNum) [0..4]
```

Comment: Oh man, it keeps getting shorter and shorter with every answer I get! Thank you!!

Comment: @Doughey `forM_[0..4]$print.nextNum`

Comment: @leftaroundabout But that needs an import, which costs a lot more than it saved.

Comment: As long as we're golfing `mapM_ print [1..5]` ;)

Comment: @luqui Yes, but that leaves the realm of "a useful answer to the original question".

Answer (score 2):

If you want it shorter, you can apply [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_):

```
mapM_ print $ map nextNum [0..4]
```

`map nexNum [0..4]` is just a list, and then `mapM_` applies monadic `print` to each element and ignores the result, which is `IO [()]` anyway.